# samsung soft keyboard bug with $ character

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I noticed that when users type the **$** character in an `EditText` a space is added.  For instance user types:

```
abcd$
```

however

```
abcd $
```

is entered in the `EditText`.  I've verified the issue on a **Note 4** running `Android 5.1.1` and an **S6 Edge** running `Android 6.0.1`. This is particularly problematic for password fields when users use the **$** character in their password because it results in user login failures.

I've verified the issue doesn't exist in the emulator for the **Nexus 5X** running `Android 5.1` and so I suspect this is a bug limited to the Samsung soft keyboard.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

see [this video](https://youtu.be/f0Q4ELBrZa8) for a demo of a Note 4 running 5.1.1

Any suggestions or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated.

Added a `TextWatcher`:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "New text: '" + s + "'");
        }
    });
```

This is from the log on the **Note 4**:

```
06-10 12:50:55.082 15187-15187/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'h'
06-10 12:50:55.237 15187-15187/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hs'
06-10 12:50:55.372 15187-15187/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hsh'
06-10 12:50:55.592 15187-15187/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hshf'
06-10 12:50:57.077 15187-15187/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hshf $'
```

when typing hshf$

This is from the **Nexus 5X** running in the emulator:

```
06-10 13:01:05.801 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'h'
06-10 13:01:06.421 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hs'
06-10 13:01:06.524 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hs'
06-10 13:01:08.848 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hsh'
06-10 13:01:09.803 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hshf'
06-10 13:01:09.908 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hshf'
06-10 13:01:13.902 3032-3032/test.apps.android.vp.org.keyboardtest D/MainActivity: New text: 'hshf$'
```

Comment: look at the text coming from the EditText and remove any spaces?

Comment: Did you try to add a TextWatcher to see the input ? `editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {});`

Comment: Added TextWatcher and updated post, thanks.

Comment: @jnellen Using `TextWatcher` you can filter out unwanted characters, `space` in your case.

Comment: I see, but in the case of a password I don't want to filter out `space`, i.e. user may have a `space` in their password.